# How to show $\lambda_1(\Omega)\ge \lambda_1(B)$ when $|\Omega|=|B|$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, riemannian-geometry, decreasing-rearrangements

$B$ is the unit ball in $\mathbb R^n$ , and $\Omega\subset \mathbb R^n$ is a domain which has same volume with $B$. $\lambda_1$ is the first eigenvalue of Laplace with Dirchlet bound condition. Then, how to show 
$$
\lambda_1(\Omega)\ge \lambda_1(B)
$$

Maybe, this is an open question. If so, any relative reference is welcome.Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll give a slightly more general answer than what you ask for by allowing $\Omega$ to have arbitrary finite measure.

First note that we have the Rayleigh quotient characterization of $\lambda_1$ on any bounded open set $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$:
$$
\lambda_1(\Omega) = \min \{ \int_\Omega |\nabla u|^2 : u \in H^1_0(\Omega) \text{ and } \int_\Omega |u|^2 =1 \}.
$$
Let $u_\Omega$ denote a minimizer, i.e. the principal eigenfunction.

Since $u_\Omega \in H^1_0(\Omega)$ we can extend it by zero outside $\Omega$ to get $\bar{u}_\Omega \in H^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$ such that 
$$
\lambda_1(\Omega) = \int_\Omega |\nabla u_\Omega|^2 = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} |\nabla \bar{u}_\Omega|^2.
$$

Now we invoke the [Polya-Szego inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%C3%B3lya%E2%80%93Szeg%C5%91_inequality), which tells us that 
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} |\nabla \bar{u}_\Omega|^2  \ge \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} |\nabla u_\Omega^\ast|^2
$$ 
where $u^\ast_\Omega$ is the symmetric decreasing rearrangement of $\bar{u}_\Omega$.  The definition of $\bar{u}_\Omega$ shows that $u^\ast_\Omega$ is supported in the ball $B$ where the ball's radius is such that $|B| = |\Omega|$.  Moreover, the $u^\ast_\Omega$ and $\bar{u}_\Omega$ are equi-distributed (have the same distribution function), so we have that 
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} |u^\ast_\Omega|^2 = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} |\bar{u}_\Omega|^2 = \int_\Omega |u_\Omega|^2 = 1.
$$
Thus 
$$
\lambda_1(\Omega) =  \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} |\nabla \bar{u}_\Omega|^2 \ge \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} |\nabla u_\Omega^\ast|^2 = \int_{B} |\nabla u_\Omega^\ast|^2 \ge \lambda_1(B).
$$

Comment: Thanks, whether this way can be used to proved $\lambda_i (\Omega)\ge \lambda_i(B)$, where $|\Omega|=|B|$.

Comment: @lanse7pty The argument above does not work. One of the reasons is that the ball does not minimize $\lambda_2$. And, any other $\lambda_i$ except perhaps if $i=3$. You can check this for more details :
https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/s10455-014-9446-9.pdf?pdf=button%20sticky

Comment: @AbdelmouksitSagueni  Thanks. Although I haven't been paying attention to it for long, the paper you mentioned imply it maybe infeasible that using geometric flow to deal eigenvalue problem (liking Polya conjugate).

Comment: @lanse7pty One of the results in  that appears in this paper (which is known amoung people  working on spectral theory) is that the second eigenvalue is not minimized by a connected set. Thus, a geometric flow may not be suitable in this context. Yet, I saw several papers where people study the evolution of some eigenvalues (for a domain in $\mathbb{R}^n$ or for Laplace-Beltrami eigenvalues for compact closed manifolds) under geometric flows as MCF , Ricci and their features .. and prove monotonicity properties under some  curvature/topological hypothesis.